# AWS Cli command is running perfectly in local system but not working in Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, aws-cli

I am using this command to create AWS Eventbridge Scheduler. It is working fine when I'm running it locally, but in jenkins it is not working.

aws scheduler create-schedule --name SendEmailOnce --schedule-expression "at(2022-11-01T11:00:00)"  --flexible-time-window "{"Mode": "OFF"}" --target '{"Arn": "arn:aws:scheduler:::aws-sdk:ec2:stopInstances", "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::96685xxxxxxx:role/service-role/Amazon_EventBridge_Invoke_Action_On_EC2_Instance_2111992150", "Input": "{"InstanceIds": ["i-0ad766a46xxxxxx"]}"}'

I'm creating AWS eventbridge scheduler with this command:
**aws scheduler create-schedule --name SendEmailOnce --schedule-expression "at(2022-11-01T11:00:00)"  --flexible-time-window "{"Mode": "OFF"}" --target '{"Arn": "arn:aws:scheduler:::aws-sdk:ec2:stopInstances", "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::96685xxxxxx:role/service-role/Amazon_EventBridge_Invoke_Action_On_EC2_Instance_2111", "Input": "{"InstanceIds": ["i-0ad766a469xxxxxxx"]}"}'**

above written command is working perfectly in local machine but not in jenkins.

**Jenkinsfile:**
pipeline {
agent any

```
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            sh"""
            aws sts get-caller-identity
            aws scheduler create-schedule --name ${name} \
                --schedule-expression "at(2022-11-01T11:00:00)" \
                --flexible-time-window '{ "Mode": "OFF" }' \
                --target "{"Arn": "arn:aws:scheduler:::aws-sdk:ec2:stopInstances", "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::966858xxxxx:role/service-role/Amazon_EventBridge_Invoke_Action_On_EC2_Instance_2111992150", "Input": "{\"InstanceIds\": [\"i-0ad766a46xxxxxx\"]}"}"
            """
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Error:**
Error parsing parameter '--target': Invalid JSON: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 188 (char 187)
JSON received: {"Arn": "arn:aws:scheduler:::aws-sdk:ec2:stopInstances", "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::9668xxxxxxxx:role/service-role/Amazon_EventBridge_Invoke_Action_On_EC2_Instance_2111992150", "Input": "{"InstanceIds": ["i-0ad766a46xxxxxxxx"]}"}

Answer (score 1):

Change double to single quotes in --target value and remove the escaped double quotes, like this:

```
--target '{"Arn": "arn:aws:scheduler:::aws-sdk:ec2:stopInstances", "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::9668xxxxxxxx:role/service-role/Amazon_EventBridge_Invoke_Action_On_EC2_Instance_2111992150", "Input": {"InstanceIds": ["i-0ad766a46xxxxxxxx"]}}'
```

It should work.